# Can the newer size buckets be used to restrict usage to >3.7" displays in Google Play?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

Do I understand things correctly if the new size buckes sw<600>dp etc do not work on Google Play? So a user can download my app but then it will crash...then this seems like a terrible idea?

I am asking because I want to support normal and large screens but some normal screens are to small so I was looking for another way.

Answer (score 0):

Google play filters the app by `<supports-screens/>` manifest tag, while the resources folder is chosen by a platform at runtime.

It will crash if you had added the resources to `sw600dp` but did not specify them for smaller screens and trying to run it on smaller screen.

Also, `sw600dp` means the screen should have at least 600dp on any smaller side, but that doesn't have to do anything with screen size in inches.

If you want to restrict the app not to run on smaller screens, use

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"/>
```

In this case the Google Play will not show the app as compatible if the screen size is 'normal' or 'small' and the screen doesn't have at least 600 dp on it's smaller size.

Comment: OK, I want normal though. So I would set normal to true and then requiresSmallestWithDp to whatever I need. But why use dp and not px. I mean it is the physical witdh of the screen that is limting, not the dp.